# Spring Data MongoDB - filtering counting and summing sub-document arrays

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

Given a MongoDB collection described by the following classes:

```
@Document(collection = "persons")
@TypeAlias("person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    private ObjectId _id = null;
    private String personName = null;
    private List<Account> accountsList = null;

    public ObjectId getId()
    {
        return _id;
    }

    public void setId(ObjectId id)
    {
        this._id = id;
    }
    public String getPersonName()
    {
        return personName;
    }

    public void setPersonName(String personName)
    {
        this.personName = personName;
    }

    public List<Account> getAccountsList()
    {
        return accountsList;
    }

    public void setAccountsList(List<Account> accountsList)
    {
        this.accountsList = accountsList;
    }
}

public class Account
{
    @Indexed(unique = false)
    private double amount = 0.0;
    private String description = null;

    public double getAmount()
    {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Using Spring Data Mongodb, how do I:

1) count the number of accounts only where the amount > x

2) retrieve only the accounts where the amount > x

3) sum the total amount of accounts only where the amount > x

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please add what you have achieved so far. You can access the documentation here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/#repositories

Comment: I was able to filter the persons:
@Query(value = "{ 'accountsList.amount': { $gt: ?1 } }")
which returns only persons who have accounts with the amount greater than X. However, it returns all the account each selected person have.
In addition, if I use
@Query(value = "{ 'accountsList.amount': { $gt: ?1 } }", count = true)
it counts the number of persons having the above accounts, not the number of accounts

Comment: You have to use aggregation. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/